# How to change past dates color of bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Can i Know how to change color of bootstrap date picker past dates. Is it possible?
Already i Used this code to generate date picker. Thank you!

```
$(function () {

    $("#regdate").datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom CSS

```
.datepicker table tr td.old{
    color:red;
}
```